# how does load command file in unix gets parameter?

Tags: c, unix

I'm trying to understand this in details.
say, I want to create a new command that does something with a file.

say, I named the new command "glw" which I do this, by creating a file
and write the implemented code "say to get first word and last word in given file"
this new file will be saved as glw.extension

so,
when I do such a thing

glw filename.text

I know that the command line, will load glw and then will execute its code.

similar to rm file.text that delete the file file.text

so, I have two questions...

first the glw should have what extension?

second,
How does the code inside "glw file" gets the parameter filename.text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first the glw should have what extension?

```
No,glw does'nt required any extension. you can genrate binary by compiling your code like
 gcc glw.c -o glw
```

then you can run your command like

```
./glw argument1 argument2
```

second, How does the code inside "glw file" gets the parameter filename.text ?

```
You can take argument by command line argument please refer http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_command_line_arguments.htm
```

Suppose you have glw.c which have following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )  
{
   if( argc == 2 )
   {
      printf("The argument supplied is %s\n", argv[1]);
   }
   else if( argc > 2 )
   {
      printf("Too many arguments supplied.\n");
   }
   else
   {
      printf("One argument expected.\n");
   }
}
```

Then compile your code using `gcc glw.c -o glw` and run your command

```
./glw argument1 argument2
```

In code argc will be number of arguments and argv will be argument values.

Comment: Thank you, this helped, so How can I make it directly get params. such that I just type glw argument1 arguemtn2 ? instead of ./glw got that?

Comment: You need to copy your glw to your /bin directory

Comment: Or make bin directory in your home directory and copy glw to bin then logout from system and then login again you can access glw

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing programs for UNIX in C as your questions tags seem to indicate, then it doesn't matter what the extension of your executable is. File extensions are a Microsoft Windows feature; they are meaningless in UNIX. You just need to make sure that the program file has execute permissions for the user trying to run it.

Your second question about getting command line arguments into your application is quite simple: they are passed to your program's `main()` function like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // will print the number of command line arguments to your program including
    // the executable name itself
    printf("%i\n", argc);

    // argv[0] will always be the executable name
    // e.g., glw
    printf("%s\n", argv[0]);

    // this will print the first command line argument to your program
    // e.g., filename.text
    printf("%s\n", argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, not sure if this what I was looking for, but I will double check. so if I have glw that has this code, so when I run unix command such glw arg1 arg2 it will automatically gets those arg1 and arg2? this what you saying

Comment: Yes, as long as by "unix command" you mean a binary executable that you compile from C or C++ code. In that case, the arguments to your command/executable are passed to your `main()` function as I've indicated above (`argv[1]` and `argv[2]`).

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet will help. If you are coding for UNIX or GNU/Linux have at look man pages for getopt(), and google for "gnu command line parser".

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argument_count, char *argument_strings[])
{

int i;

for(i=0; i<argument_count; i++)
    printf("argument number=%d   argument=%s\n",i,argument_strings[i]);

return 0;
}
```